# How to compare 2 Lists in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, list

I am trying to compare 2 lists to each other. Both lists have tens of thousands of entries.

My idea so far has been to use 2 ArrayLists and comparing them element by element. However I have been told that comparing too much can corrupt eclipse. No idea if this is true. Though better safe than sorry.

If you know any tips on comparing tens of thousands of Strings, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried the implementation you are thinking of?

Comment: What would be the result of such comparison? Can you give us examples? Can you share your coding attemps and show where it did not work?

Comment: Eclipse is just your IDE, it's not something that can get corrupted because you run an application.

Comment: @PhillipMartin Not yet. As stated above, I did have a few concerns.

Comment: @alainlompo As stated above, I have not tried it due to memory leaks. I am somewhat new to Java.

Comment: Insn't there something in the Apache CollectionUtils to do this?  https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html

Comment: @djangofan to be honest, I have not a large idea what Guava is.

Comment: Sorry, I think you want retainAll, disjunction, union,  and removeAll methods from Apache CollectionUtils...

Comment: Both the Guava and Apache Commons libraries have stuff to compare collections (I think at least, definitely for sets)

Comment: Also, you may want to consider using a Set, rather than a List. If all the elements of the List are unique (or are supposed to be) in that they occur only once, a Set can be far more useful. It wont let you put an entry in twice and you can just call .equals() to compare two sets. If you use a common HashSet, the entries won't maintain their insertion order, but that's not often what you want or need when using a Set anyway.

Comment: For comparing element by element, a `Comparator` is useful.

Answer (score 0):

What does mean "corrupt eclipse"?

However no, if you have two arraylist and you want to know if they are equal, you have to compare all the variables unless you find difference or end of a list. The complexity is `O(n)` - linear - which is the best you can get without some pre processing (which itself would be `O(n)` in best case).

Comment: I was thinking about a memory leak.

With O(n) you are talking about the Big O notation? This describes the limiting point of a function. My question would be how to put O(n) into code.

Maybe by requesting the next greatest Array? 

Array[next array amount...]

Thanks in advanced :)

Comment: There's no memory leak involved, but I'm not convinced you completely understand what a memory leak is, perhaps look that up?

Comment: Already got my dictionary out. This has pointed to the word I did not understand. Thank you :)

Comment: @SebastiaanvandenBroek My definition completely missed the point. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to compare each individual elements in both arrays try sorting the array and then using a for loop to run through it

Answer (score 0):

If you are comparing 2 numbers, the expected output can be -
    -> first greater than second
    -> first less than second
    -> first equal to second

But, what do you mean by comparing 2 lists? Are you planning to compare the length of both the lists? If so, you get the size of both the lists and compare them.

If you want to compare every element in the list with the every other element, it would mean, you are trying to sort the list. If you are planning to do the same thing with 2 lists, it might mean- you are trying to merge-sort both the lists. Meaning, you are creating 1 list containing all the elements of both the lists in sorted order.

This following video can help you for understanding merge-sort.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EeQ8pwjQxTM

This code would have an average time complexity of O(n log n). And for the lists with tens of thousands of elements, the algorithm would have considerable time complexity, but eclipse wouldn't corrupt. Worst case, if your code is not written properly, memory leaks can cause a problem in the JVM.

I hope my answer helps you. I might help you in a better way if your question is clearer and more specific.

Comment: I am talking about finding all of the duplicates within a list. I have a task to find he duplicates and only the duplicates within an email list of tens of thousands.

Thanks :)

Comment: Make use of Set in Java. Sets do not have duplicates. Set<E> yourSet  = new HashSet<E>(<yourList>); This can build you a set and if the size of your list is different from the size of your list, it means that your list has duplicates. <OR> If you don't have a problem of space complexity, use a hashmap. You can also know which all elements are duplicated.